# SQL Server: If, Else Select Statements to populate a grid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to populate a data-grid with information from my table. One of the fields in this table is `Active` basically used as a flag set to either `True` or `False`.

I have a query on my website that checks if the currently logged-in user's is an administrator or not.

Using that in a TOKEN I can input [LSX:IsAdmin] that will return either true or false.

All data in my table that is NOT flagged `Active=True` i'd like to display only to Administrators which is what my TOKEN is for.

I'm having some difficulties with my query below to achieve that.

```
IF('LSX:IsAdmin'='True')
SELECT * FROM SaleEvents
ELSE 
SELECT * FROM SaleEvents WHERE Active = True
```

Error Message `Invalid object name 'SaleEvents'.`

Comment: Do you have table called `SaleEvents` in `dbo` schema of your database

Comment: Yes I have SaleEvents table in the DB

Comment: Is it created in `dbo` schema ?

Comment: I believe so, how can I check?

Comment: `select TABLE_SCHEMA from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'SaleEvents'` run this query and check

Comment: Dosen't show anything in query results. Just a Field "Table-SChema" thats blank.

Comment: Then you don't have table called `SaleEvents` that explains the reason for error message

Comment: Ah, I see my problem I missed my prefix in the table name, Now i'm getting invalid Column Name 'True' thats where I think I messed up the IF statement.

Comment: Try "Where active = 1" ;-)

Comment: @AlexP depending on whether your `SaleEvents.Active` column is a `BIT`/`INT` or a `VARCHAR` or similar, you need either `WHERE Active = 1` or `WHERE UPPER(Active) = 'TRUE'`.

Comment: I think it's not a ms sql server (your tag 'sql-server' means Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: did you tried with out if ?? it seems the table does not exist, right click on your table and do select from there , then you can get the schema name in the query , then use that schema name here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: How to find schema name and table name]

[image: Default schema]

First picture shows how to find out schema name (CIS, dbo, TestCars, TestDoc, TestMoney). 'dbo' schema usually exists and default.

However, you can change default schema for user (second picture).

You do not specify schema name in your query, that's why default schema is used.

To specify a schema name you should add it before table name

```
SELECT * FROM <your schema>.SaleEvents WHERE Active = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I believe the issue to be something to do with my IF statement not the table name or schema.

Comment: Try to execute `SELECT` (both versions) without `IF` statement and post your result here. Is it good? You wrote in comments that you've corrected the query. Please attach new version of your query too